# Julia and unixODBC

Tags: odbc, julia

So: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit; I've set up unixODBC, and I'm trying to open an ODBC connection in Julia. I've tried this on both stable 0.20 and the latest nightly of Julia 0.30; I'm using ODBC.jl version 0.3.1. The problem I hit is that Julia seems to not be loading my DSNs. For instance:

```
ulia> ODBC.listdsns()
0x2 Array{String,2}
```

On the other hand, `isql` can connect to my DSNs just fine (so unixODBC is set up correctly). So... now I'm not sure how to proceed. I've tried using `ODBC.advancedconnect()`, but oddly, I get the same error message as when I try to use a DSN:

```
IM002: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

There is a note about setting `const odbc_dm` on the ODBC.jl github page; I can't find any libs that sound like the one that note is talking about, but maybe that's the problem?

Any suggestions appreciated -- I don't particularly know how to proceed with this one, so this posting feels a little spare on details. If there's more information that would be helpful, just let me know and I'll get it posted.

Comment: Have you tried creating an issue on the ODBC.jl github repo? That's usually a good way to get a quick answer from the package developers.

Comment: No, I haven't yet -- was trying to sort through all the possible "it's a problem on my end" things first :-P I'll reach out via github in a little bit if I don't get traction here. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

ODBC.jl developer here. Yeah, it's probably because the package isn't finding your unixODBC library. Once you run `using ODBC`, type `ODBC.odbc_dm` to see what the package is picking up.  You may have to manually set it (by modifying the ODBC_types.jl file in your package directory, or I can add some better logic to pick it up (better long-term). Feel free to open an issue at the repo and we can troubleshoot from there.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying! `ODBC.odbc_dm`just returns `"libodbc"`, which is probably the problem. I've opened [this issue](https://github.com/karbarcca/ODBC.jl/issues/34) on the repo for further fixing.